# const type to const alias in C++11

Tags: c++, alias

I am using Clang included in Xcode 4.6.2 (4H1003).

```
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
```

Currently my compiler doesn't make a compile error for this code.

```
using AA = int const;
static AA const aa  =   0;
```

Because I am not familiar with accurate C++11 specs, I can't know what is correct behavior.

1. Error for double `const` keyword.
2. `const` on `using` is not allowed.
3. This is some special case.
4. This is compiler bug.

What is expected behavior by standard?

Comment: [dcl.type.cv]/1 "Redundant cv-qualifications are ignored. [Note: For example, these could be introduced by typedefs.—end note ]"

Comment: My question is related or duplicated to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781222/duplicate-const-qualifier-allowed-in-c-but-not-in-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why compiler doesn't give error when typedef const pointer is used with extra const?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534126/why-compiler-doesnt-give-error-when-typedef-const-pointer-is-used-with-extra-co)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was already allowed back with C++98 - cv-qualifiers can be introduced multiple times through typedef names and template parameters - they're simply collapsed. If this wasn't allowed, generic code would have a lot of problems. The same thing happens for references too.

`§7.1.6.1 [dcl.type.cv] p1`:

> There are two *cv-qualifiers*, `const` and `volatile`. [...]
>   **Redundant cv-qualifications are ignored.** [ *Note:* For example, these could be introduced by typedefs.*—end note* ]